# All possible generators for a fractional factorial design

Tags: matlab

Using the matlab function `fracfactgen` I can generate the generators for a two-level fractional-factorial design. Let's say that I have `Factor = 7` and I need the generators for a design plan of resolution 3.

```
generators = fracfactgen('a b c d e f g',[],3)

generators = 

    'a'
    'b'
    'c'
    'abc'
    'bc'
    'ac'
    'ab'
```

Now, I know that this is just one of the 16 possibile alternative to build a `2^(7-4)` DoE plan, so **how can I obtain all possibile generator combinations**?

*Please Note*: The other combinations are:

```
            case 1
                'a b c -ab -ac -bc -abc'
            case 2
                'a b c -ab -ac -bc abc'
            case 3
                'a b c -ab -ac bc -abc'
            case 4
                'a b c -ab -ac bc abc'
            case 5
                'a b c -ab ac -bc -abc'
            case 6
                'a b c -ab ac -bc abc'
            case 7
                'a b c -ab ac bc -abc'
            case 8
                'a b c -ab ac bc abc'
            case 9
                'a b c ab -ac -bc -abc'
            case 10
                'a b c ab -ac -bc abc'
            case 11
                'a b c ab -ac bc -abc'
            case 12
                'a b c ab -ac bc abc'
            case 13
                'a b c ab ac -bc -abc'
            case 14
                'a b c ab ac -bc abc'
            case 15
                'a b c ab ac bc -abc'
            case 16
                'a b c ab ac bc abc'
```

Comment: Is `fracfact` not giving you all these outcomes?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin `fracfact` needs the generators to build a Fractional factorial design based on the generators. I need to automatically create all possibile generator combinations (case 1 to 16) to let `fracfact` create all possibile designs. Is it more clear now? Sorry but it's a tricky question and I'm not so good in explain myself.